# Error :Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

Hi I am learning Scala Spark, and trying to build a simple code. But getting an error as shown below. I have imported all the dependencies in pom.xml file form maven repo also. but still it is giving me class not found exception. Please help. Below in the screenshot of the error, code and pom.xml file.

```
 Exception in thread "main"     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession$
at com.first.spark.Demo$.main(Demo.scala:13)
at com.first.spark.Demo.main(Demo.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 2 more
```

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Scala_2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Spak Sql Code

```
package com.first.spark

import org.apache.avro.LogicalTypes.Date
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Month
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, functions}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{avg, col, month, round, year}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}


object Demo {
  def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = {

val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .appName(name = "ReadMultilintJson")
  .config("spark.master", "local")
  .getOrCreate()

val aaon = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true)
  .csv("/Users/p0p029i/Downloads/Spark_Sql Datasets/614_m6_StockMarket_DataSets/AAON.csv")

val aaondf = aaon.withColumn("Year", year(col("Date")))
  .withColumn(colName = "Month", month(col("Date")))

val aaongroup = aaondf.groupBy("Year", "Month")
  .agg(round(avg(col("Adj Close")),2)).as("AvgClsPrice")

val aaonsorted = aaongroup.orderBy(col("year").desc,col("Month").desc)

aaonsorted.show()

  }
}
```

Comment: Use the same version of Spark Core and Spark SQL

Answer (score 4):

Using the provided scope means you need provide the dependency at runtime in the classpath.
To solve your issue you have two solutions :

- Remove the provided scope from the spark-sql dependency
- In IntelliJ, edit your Run/Debug configuration and check the "Include dependencies with Provided scope" box